# Can I transform MongoDB Document to contain an Array inside an Array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to transform documents that look something like this

```
{ "_id": 1,
  "created_at": DateTimeObject,
  "daily": [{ "impressions":13,
              "clicks": 13,
              "day": "2015-01-01" },
            { "impressions":15,
              "clicks": 15,
              "day": "2015-01-02" },
            { "impressions":20,
              "clicks": 20,
              "day": "2015-01-03" }]
}
```

to

```
{ "_id": 1,
  "impressions": [["2015-01-01", 13], 
                  ["2015-01-02", 15], 
                  ["2015-01-03", 20]],
  "clicks": [["2015-01-01", 13], 
             ["2015-01-02", 15], 
             ["2015-01-03", 20]] }
```

currently using unwind and group I can get the data in the below format

```
{ "_id": 1,
  "impressions": [{ "date": "2015-01-01", "value":13], 
                  {"date":"2015-01-02", "value":15}, 
                  {"date":"2015-01-03", "value":20}],
  "clicks": [{"date": "2015-01-01", "value":13}, 
             {"date": "2015-01-01", "value":15}, 
             {"date": "2015-01-01", "value":20}] }
```

I don't want to do this outside the db because there are around 150 - 200 line charts that need to be generated from similar documents and would prefer to just have the transformation.

**EDIT**: *Would this be possible with map reduce ?*

Comment: You could insert your data in your needed schema.

Comment: @Simulant yes I could but that format is idle for other queries also. So I don't think that is an option at the moment

Comment: @Simulant can this be done using map reduce ?

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb can't support inner array. you need to write with unwind and group only.

Comment: According to me you should write as you said in last code.

Comment: That's the last resort :)

Comment: What do you mean, can't support inner array?

Comment: According to me we cannot use inner array in MongoDB.